# Material Ui code is working perfectly in codepen but not in VSCODE?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material-UI to create "Material Tabs" in my ReactJS project, this code is working properly in SANDBOX, but not in my VS CODE. What should I do?

I checked Node to be installed, checked and install all dependencies versions from NPM.
   I also checked it out. [check it](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/14416), but I couldn't understand it.

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import SwipeableViews from "react-swipeable-views";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/styles";
import Tabs from "@material-ui/core/Tabs";
import Tab from "@material-ui/core/Tab";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
function TabContainer({ children, dir }) {
  return (
    <Typography component="div" dir={dir} style={{ padding: 8 * 3 }}>
      {children}
    </Typography>
  );
}
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
    width: 500
  }
}));

class Feature extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: 0 };
  }
  handleChange() {
    this.state.value === 0
      ? this.setState({ value: 1 })
      : this.setState({ value: 0 });
  }
  render() {
    const classes = this.props;
    const theme = this.props;
    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <Tabs
          value={this.state.value}
          onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
          indicatorColor="primary"
          textColor="primary"
        >
          <Tab label="A" />
          <Tab label="B" />
        </Tabs>
        <SwipeableViews
          axis={theme.direction === "rtl" ? "x-reverse" : "x"}
          index={this.state.value}
        >
          <TabContainer dir={theme.direction}>Item One</TabContainer>
          <TabContainer dir={theme.direction}>Item Two</TabContainer>
        </SwipeableViews>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
Feature.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
export default withStyles(useStyles)(Feature);
```

And my **package.json** looks like

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.9.2",
    "@material-ui/docs": "^3.0.0-alpha.9",
    "@material-ui/styles": "^4.0.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.8.5",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.5",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.8",
    "react-slick": "^0.23.2",
    "react-swipeable-views": "^0.13.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "styled-components": "^4.2.0"
  }
```

I expect the output as given by [SANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/embed/material-demo-tcrbr), but got this error instead

```
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
    width: 500
  }
}));
```

in above code.

Comment: material-ui version?

Comment: I am running the same code in VSCode on the local machine and not getting any errors, beside `dir proptypes`

Comment: @B4BIPIN did it solve the issue?

Comment: No, @HRK44, I upgraded material version from "^3.9.2" to "^4.0.1". But this didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your sandbox you are using `@material-ui/core latest` version (which currently is `4.0.1`) and in your VS Code package.json it's version `3.9.2`. I'm pretty sure that's the issue, try both with the exact same version instead of using `latest`.

See here : https://codesandbox.io/embed/material-demo-1j37n

Comment: But as I searched on React Official website, they are saying React Hooks (in my code makeStyles) are used only with Function, not Classes.
[check](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-from-react-functions)

Comment: Please Check it. 
With Function [Function](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-9me6x), and with Class [Class](https://codesandbox.io/embed/material-demo-l6vlz?fontsize=14).

Comment: @B4BIPIN in the sandbox it's working correctly with the correct versions, and the error is the same as the one you mentioned with using lower version. That's seem strange that it's not working with the latest 4.x version

Comment: Yes, You were right. This problem occurred due to confliction of dependencies. But I realise this when I created a new project and match dependencies. Thanks to @HRK44